# Why cant I compress and archive files using tar?

Tags: bash, shell

I'm trying to take my `results` after attempting to change the permission of the first 5 files with the earliest modification timestamp, then take the files with no modification made on them from previous command & place them into a variable. Take this variable, compress them and archive them into tar.gz archive file.

The first half of the code isn't great as I am still learning. Every time I try to run the `tar` command for my variable `unmodified` I get the error shown below and I believe it is because of the way `unmodified` might be set up? Does it need to be put into a array? Any help will be appreciated, thank you.

```
echo "Files with the earliest timestamps: "
echo "--------------------"
results=$(find ~/Main/  -type f -printf '%T+ %f\n' | sort | tail -n 5) #In Main directory, find all file types, print last modification date and time, separated by '+' and display the file name on a new line.
echo "$results" #Variable displayed

for results in $results; do
       test -f "$results" && chmod  -R 744 "$results" #For every file found in $results variable, change permission to rwx--r--r-- or 744.
done

echo "Files permission not changed: "
echo "-----------------------"
unmodified=$(find ~/Main/ -maxdepth 2 -type f -printf '%f\n' ! -perm 744 | xargs -0 ) #In the /Main/ directory, in root level 1, then one sub-directory (level 2) all file types, to remove any without permission of rwx--r--r-- aka 744.
echo "$unmodified" #To confirm successfully completed.

tar -czvf ~/Main/Backup/Archive1.tar.gz "$unmodified" #Attempt to archive files found but something is wrong with how the $unmodfied is set.
```

Error:

```
tar: Notes_14.txt\nResults_14.txt\nNotes_13.txt\nResults_13.txt\nNotes_11.txt\nResults_11.txt\nNotes_5.txt\nResults_5.txt\nNotes_17.txt\nResults_17.txt\nNotes_9.txt\nResults_9.txt\nResults_10.txt\nNotes_10.txt\nNotes_18.txt\nResults_18.txt\nNotes_3.txt\nResults_3.txt\nNotes_6.txt\nResults_6.txt\nNotes_19.txt\nResults_19.txt\nNotes_1.txt\nResults_1.txt\nNotes_7.txt\nResults_7.txt\nNotes_8.txt\nResults_8.txt\nResults_20.txt\nNotes_20.txt\nNotes_16.txt\nResults_16.txt\nResults_3.bak\nArchive1.tar.gz\nNotes_3.bak\nNotes_12.txt\nResults_12.txt\nResults_2.txt\nNotes_2.txt\nResults_15.txt\nNotes_15.txt\nResults_4.txt\nNotes_4.txt: Cannot stat: File name too long
tar: Exiting with failure status due to previous errors
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to remove the \n markers in the unmodified variable. This can be done with parameter expansion

```
tar -czvf ~/Main/Backup/Archive1.tar.gz "${unmodified//\\n/ }"
```

Use forward slashes to signify that you want to change "\n" to " ". The extra / before \n signifies that all occurrences of \n should be changed.

Comment: Thanks for your response. It's still bringing the same error message. Would I need to change the parameters in the `unmodified` variable where I've set it? Apologises if I'm not using the right terms.

Comment: `unmodified` contains literal linefeeds, not the digraph `\n`.

Answer (score 0):

`tar` requires each file to be a separate argument. You are passing a *single*, linefeed-delimited argument that `tar` does not split into multiple file names. (It cannot, since a linefeed is a valid character to include in a file name.)

Ordinarily, I would recommend building an array of file names, but doing so using `find` is tricky, so let's try an alternate approach: use `tar` to *append* files to a tar file as `find` identifies which files to archive.

```
tarfile=~/Main/Backup/Archive1.tar.gz
find ~/Main -maxdepth 2 -type f ! -perm 744 ! -name "$tarfile" \
   -exec tar rf "$tarfile" {} +
gzip "$tarfile"
```

The `r` option to `tar` is like `c`, except it appends files to an existing archive rather than creating a new archive. (It creates the archive if it does not exist.)

Using `-exec ... +` minimizes the number of times `tar` will run, with `find` passing as many filenames as will fit on the command line instead of calling `tar` once for each file. (Though the I/O cost of copying the files into the archive likely dwarfs the startup cost of `tar`, so it's probably a minor optimization.)

I'm compressing the file once after `find` is done adding files; I *think* this will be more efficient than repeatedly using `tar zrf`.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Ive only just managed to try this out, it's bringing me new errors now. 
`find: warning: Unix filenames usually don't contain slashes (though pathnames do).  etc etc ..` `tar: Removing leading /' from member names`
`gzip:/home/local/USERS/pbssoker/students/Backup/Archive.tar.gz already has .gz suffix -- unchanged ` I read if I add `--force` to the gzip line it get rids of the error, not sure if that is correct. Secondly, I read if I put `--exclude` in the tar line it should help too but I have no idea where or if that is correct? Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: That may be what it says: just a warning. I don't get that on macOS using either the BSD or GNU versions of `tar`.